# How extract Id from event class

Tags: java, spring, methods, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a model class "Person" that have four attribute:

```
private final static String id; 
private final static String name;
private final static String lastName;
private final static String age;
```

Now I must create a event class which contains the list of person ID(so I suppose a method that returns a list) to be synchronized(all those existing in the system).
How could I do it as cleanly as possible? Thanks a lot.

My event class:

```
public class MyEventSync extends AbstractEvent{
private final PersonModel PersonModel;

public MyEventSync(PersonModel personModel)
{
    this.personModel = personModel;
}

public List<String> getPersonsById()
{
    List<String> personModelListId = new ArrayList<>();
    personModelListId.add(personModel.getId());
    return personModelListId;
}
```

or another method:

```
public List<PersonModel> getPerson()
{
   List<PersonModel> personList = new ArrayList<>();
   personList.add(personModel);
   return personList;
}
```

Comment: does your Event have id('s)? or do you mean the id of a specific person? I assume you are using getters?

Comment: @Stultuske there can be more person registered in the system and I have to update them all, the important thing is that I have a list of ids that are one or more, it doesn't matter.

Comment: my event class: public class MyEvent extends AbstractEvent{ private final PersonModel personModel; public MyEvent(PersonModel personModel) {this.personModel = personModel;} public List<String> getPersonById()
    { List<String> personModelListId = new ArrayList<>();
        personModelListId.add(personModel.getId());
        return personModelListId; } or another mehod: public List<PersonModel> getPerson()
    {
       List<PersonModel> personList = new ArrayList<>();
       personList.add(personModel);
       return personList;
    }

Comment: You've declared your attributes as `static`, so they are not per instance, but per class.

Comment: Don't add information in comments, please edit your question.

Comment: when you create a method 'getPersonById', you are supposed to pass an id as parameter.

Comment: @Stultuske and then?

Comment: and then you use that id to find the corresponding object

Comment: I don't understand what is your main goal. What are you trying to achieve? Can you elaborate more on that? Thanks!

Comment: yes. I must generate event (class event) that contains a list of ID of person that are present in the system, but not I have understand how I do.

Comment: I'm sure that I must create a method that return a list of ID (ID is a String type into class PersonModel) but now i have a lapsus for the right implementation of this method.

Comment: Please define "system". Is it a database? Another service? Data in memory in your application?

Comment: yes in database

Comment: Then you need a way to get the data from there. In Spring that is usually a Repository. Do you have any? If you do please add it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @JoãoDias Repository no, Service yes

Comment: Then how do you get the data from the database?